# Can I accept an answer after some lenghty period of time?

Tags: support, answers

I have recently asked this question: [Tips to avoid forgetting a bag](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/107796/tips-to-avoid-forgetting-a-bag)

It received quite a few good answers, however I am really not in a position yet to accept any one of them - these are tips that I have to try first and see what works best for me. Ideally I would need to take few more trips to understand that.

Would it be ok to postpone ticking a single answer for quite some time, perhaps even a month or two?

Comment: You can even choose to _not_ accept any. Accepting one isn't _that_ necessary.

Comment: Alternatively, remember that you can accept one that looks good now, then come back later, un-accept it, and accept a different one, should another prove in the field to be of more use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Would it be ok to postpone ticking a single answer for quite some time, perhaps even a month or two?

Yes, it's okay. You don't have to accept an answer if you're not sure which one is the most helpful or if you don't like any of the answers. You can even add your own answer at a later time and accept it instead :)